# Workflows status bar doesn't show colors and states

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

i'm working on OpenERP workflows. All flows are working fine except status bar widget doesnt show states and doesnt reflect colors that i have writen in view. Can anyone help me out please?

```
class workflow_example2(osv.osv):
    def mymod_new(self, cr, uid, ids):
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'new' })
        return True

    def mymod_assigned(self, cr, uid, ids):
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'assigned' })
        return True

    def mymod_negotiation(self, cr, uid, ids):
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'negotiation' })
        return True

    def mymod_won(self, cr, uid, ids):
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'won' })
        return True

    def mymod_lost(self, cr, uid, ids):
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'lost' })
        return True

    _name = 'workflow.example2'
    _columns = {
        'abc':fields.char('abc', size=20),
        'state': fields.selection([
        ('new','New'),
        ('assigned','Assigned'),
        ('negotiation','Negotiation'),
        ('won','Won'),
        ('lost','Lost')], 'Stage', readonly=True, track_visibility='onchange'),
        'field_1': fields.char('Field_1', size=20),
        'field_2': fields.char('Field_2', size=16),        
    }
```

workflow_example2()

```
<!Workflow xlm>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="workflow" id="wkf_mymod2">
            <field name="name">workflow.wkf</field>
            <field name="osv">workflow.example2</field>
            <field name="on_create">True</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_new">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mymod2" />
            <field name="flow_start">True</field>
            <field name="name">new</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">mymod_new()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_assigned">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mymod2" />
            <field name="name">assigned</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">mymod_assigned()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_negotiation">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mymod2" />
            <field name="name">negotiation</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">mymod_negotiation()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_won">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mymod2" />
            <field name="name">won</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">mymod_won()</field>    
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>            
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_lost">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mymod2" />
            <field name="name">lost</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">mymod_lost()</field>
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="t1">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_new" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_assigned" />
            <field name="signal">mymod_assigned</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="t2">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_assigned" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_negotiation" />
            <field name="signal">mymod_negotiation</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="t3">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_negotiation" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_won" />
            <field name="signal">mymod_won</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="t4">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_negotiation" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_lost" />
            <field name="signal">mymod_lost</field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

example_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_wf_example_form2" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">workflow.example.form</field>
            <field name="model">workflow.example2</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Workflow Example" version="7.0">
                <header>
                        <button name="mymod_assigned" string="New" class="oe_highlight oe_view_mode_only"  states="new" />
                        <button name="mymod_negotiation" string="In negotiation" class="oe_highlight oe_view_mode_only"  states="assigned" />
                        <button name="mymod_won" string="won" states="negotiation" class="oe_highlight oe_view_mode_only"  />
                        <button name="mymod_lost" string="lost" states="negotiation" class="oe_highlight oe_view_mode_only"  />
                        <label string="Draft Invoice" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('status','&lt;&gt;','new')]}"/>                        
                        <field name="status" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="new,assigned,negotiation" statusbar_colors='{"new":"blue","assigned":"blue"}'/>
                        <field name="status" invisible="1"/>                        
                </header>
                <sheet string ="Workflow">
                    <group col="2" colspan="0">    
                        <field name="field_1"/>
                        <field name="field_2"/>                        
                    </group>                   
                </sheet>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <div>
                        <H2>
                        <label string="History and Comments"/>                
                        </H2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_wf_example_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">workflow.example.tree</field>
            <field name="model">workflow.example2</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Workflow Example">
                        <field name="field_1"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- ACTIONS -->
        <record id="act_wf_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Form workflow</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">workflow.example2</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_wf_example_form2"/>
        </record>
        <!--  MENUITEM -->
        <menuitem name="workflow" action="act_wf_form" id="menu_wf_form" sequence="1" />

    </data>
</openerp>
```

regards
Ali Khan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're on OpenERP 7 (now Odoo) there are no customizable statusbar colors in the webclient (active status always blue). Plus you've defined the field 'status' twice in your form view, that means the real value will be in the second field and the first defined field will be empty. Don't define a field twice in form views, except for embedded views within the view.